# Map type in SOAP Service

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm trying to consume a web service in Python using suds that contains a reference to Map type from the namespace http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap. I'm guessing that this is some non standard type that is generated in Java. Here is a part of the wsdl file:

```xml
<wsdl:definitions
    xmlns:tns="..."
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
    mlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
    name="controller"
    targetNamespace="...">
```

and then somewhere in the file there is:

```xml
<wsdl:part name="Result" type="ns2:Map"/>
```

When I try try to parse the file I get

```python
TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Map, http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap, )'
```

The only solution I'm able to come up with is getting the wsdl file and manually change it so it defines the Map type, but I want to know is there a better way of fixing this issue.

Comment: How did you add the Map type?

Comment: I added the Map type manually in when retrieving the WSDL. Since I knew what parameters could come up as keys and what type the values of those keys should be it was easy to create the type and just manually add it to the file before creating the suds object.
It is not the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.